# Can I check via script if my NotesView is corrupt?

Tags: xpages

Last week I worked on an incident, where it was stated that a Java agent caused to terminate a server. First dagnose was that objects probably were not being recycled in a sufficient manner.

After some testing (and bring down the server multiple times :-) ) I notified in my Notes client that the view was corrupt.

I could have avoid this if I were able to check if a view is OK or not.

- for a database I can check if it exists
- for a view I can check if it exists

But can I also check if a view is in good condition or not? or is only a client (Notes, Admin) capable of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was a programmatic way Patrick.  The fixup task (load fixup -C) is one of the sure fire ways to get details of corruption, but not helpful to you in this scenario.

Comment: hi Rob, the cause of corruption is probably an update on the database that ran the night before. well yeah, a couple of grey hairs more...